# How do you determine if a visitor to a sitecore page is unique?

Tags: sitecore

I would like to determine if a user viewing a sitecore page is unique (first time visit to that page). I attempted to use the following code but it seems to only be session based. Is there an alternative that will work across sessions?

```
    protected bool First_Visit()
    {
        var pageId = ActionItem.ID.ToGuid();

        var visitCount = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Visitor.DataContext.Pages.Select(pagesRow =>
            pagesRow.ItemId.Equals(pageId)
        ).Count();

        return visitCount == 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've come up with that seems to work as expected across sessions:

```
    protected bool First_Visit()
    {
        var pageId = ActionItem.ID.ToGuid();
        var visitor = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Visitor;
        var visits = from visit in visitor.DataContext.Visits
                     from page in visit.GetPages()
                     where page.ItemId.Equals(pageId)
                     select page;

        return visits.Count() == 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do `Tracker.Visitor.LoadAll()` first. This will load the data of all visits for that particular visitor.

**Edit**

Having said that, it goes without saying that if a visitor comes from an unidentified device (i.e. an existing visitor coming on a device they haven't identified themselves on) it will count as the first visit for that user.